# How to display data in angular js by using ng-table along with dynamic data-title with nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the json which I need to populate in the ng - table. Column name should be dynamic

```
var data = [
          {
          "name": "abc",
          "Data": [
            {key: "FIRST_COL", value: 50},
            {key: "SECOND_COL", value: 10},
            {key: "THIRD_COL", value: 30},
            {key: "FOURTH_COL", value: 40}
          ]
          }, {
            "name": "xyz",
            "Data": [
            {key: "FIRST_COL", value: 300},
            {key: "SECOND_COL", value: 20},
            {key: "THIRD_COL", value: 400},
            {key: "FOURTH_COL", value: 60}
            ]
          }
            ];
```

And table should be like this :

Table structure :

```
FIRST_COL    SECOND_COL     THIRD_COL       FOURTH_COL
50              10              30              40
300             20              400             60
```

Comment: Have you tried to write any code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-repeat` to populate the data.

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.tableData = [
          {
          "name": "abc",
          "Data": [
            {key: "FIRST_COL", value: 50},
            {key: "SECOND_COL", value: 10},
            {key: "THIRD_COL", value: 30},
            {key: "FOURTH_COL", value: 40}
          ]
          }, {
            "name": "xyz",
            "Data": [
            {key: "FIRST_COL", value: 300},
            {key: "SECOND_COL", value: 20},
            {key: "THIRD_COL", value: 400},
            {key: "FOURTH_COL", value: 60}
            ]
          }
            ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
 <table>
  <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="val in tableData[0].Data">{{val.key}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in tableData">
      <td ng-repeat="val in item.Data">{{val.value}}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use ng-table and column name should set dynamically using data-title